# Meaning/use of ように in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 鳥の絵が得意になり、クリスマスにハトの絵を贈ってくれる**ようにもなった**。

I cannot understand the meaning of ようにもなった in this sentence.

I know that

> 鳥の絵が得意になり、

means "I became good/strong at drawing birds and..."

> クリスマスにハトの絵を贈ってくれるようにもなった.

Could the meaming of this be "I received for Christmas a drawing of a dove"?

Comment: Two questions: What if the subject of the first clause wasn’t “I”? And are you familiar with the set phrase ようになる？

Comment: I'd like to answer this question, but I'm not sure whether the second clause refer to a single event, multiple events, or either one depending on context. Could someone advise?

Comment: @mamster Yes I am familiar with it...could it be that the も emphasizes the change?
The text is about this cram school the author used to attend, so maybe this sentence refers to the fact that before attending the school he wasn't good at drawing birds, and he even received a drawing for Christmas (which he never did before).
What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries say するようになる means "get to do" or "come to do". You can use these words. And this も is close to "even".

So this sentence would be translated as "He(She) became good at drawing birds, and even he(she) got to give me a picture of a dove for Christmas."

Answer (score 1):

Without other context, I would assume the subject of the first clause can't be the speaker; otherwise it would mean:

> I became good at drawing birds, and eventually I received a picture of a dove for Christmas.

So I would interpret it as:

> They (or he/she) became good at drawing birds, and eventually they gave me a picture of a dove for Christmas.

But if, as you say, it's a memoir about the author's own experience in an art class, then I suppose it must be the former. I'm using "eventually" as a translation of ようにもなる, but "even" would also be a good gloss.